# Get list of pull requests in Repository

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I want to get all pull requests in repository but this seems impossible. I was able to find only pull requests comments (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/pullrequests+Resource)

How could one use this resource if he cannot get request ids? Is there any way to get pull requests?

Answer (score 3):

The new API is now out and list of pull requests works fine

```
https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/repositories/YOUR_NAME/REPO_NAME/pullrequests
```

Comment: Attempting to post to that URL gives me the error "Bad Request".

Comment: I posted this answer 2 years ago, things might have changed ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is officially impossible. But [promised](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/3442/pullrequest-listing-api-is-necessary-bb#comment-3636265) to be fixed soon.